# Правильный предлог со словом "пробуждать"

Tags: предлоги

Меня терзают смутные сомнения:

- Пробудить у ребенка желание заниматься.
- Пробудить в ребенке желание заниматься.

Что правильно? Какой предлог верный?

- Это пробуждает у Вас желание съесть его.
- Это пробуждает в Вас желание съесть его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь приведены оба варианта.

будить
(вызывать к жизни, возбуждать) ***что-л. в ком и у кого.*** Будить в женщине (у женщины) любопытство.

[Пунктуация и управление в русском языке. Д.Э. Розенталь.](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/)

Answer (score 0):

*Пробудить в ребенке желание* — значит найти отклик в его душе, т. е. согласия его внутреннего мира с внешним. *Пробудить у ребенка желание* — почти то же, но не имеет такого веса и обоюдных усилий, ведь и от котёнка можно достаточно просто такого добиться.

Answer (score -1):

"в ребёнке", если речь идёт о ребёнке вообще и "у ребёнка", если говорится о конкретном ребёнке.

Comment: Очень спорно. Мнение требует пояснения по крайней мере.